# If $E|f(Z)|<\infty$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$ then is $E|f( Z/\alpha)|<\infty$ for some $0<\alpha<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function that is integrable w.r.t. the density of $Z$ i.e. $E|f(Z)|<\infty$, in other words $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|e^{-x^2/2}dx<\infty$ (ignoring the constant multipliers in the normal density).

> Can we conclude that there exists some $0<\alpha<1$ such that $E|f(Z/\alpha)|<\infty$? That is, does there exist some $0<\alpha<1$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|e^{-x^2\alpha^2/2}dx<\infty$?

Unfortunately $\int |f(x)|e^{-x^2\alpha^2/2}dx =\int |f(x)|e^{-x^2/2}e^{x^2(1-\alpha^2)/2}dx$ and this $e^{x^2(1-\alpha^2)/2}$ explodes since $0<\alpha<1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^{x^2/2}/(1+x^2)$ is a counterexample